# Is there difference between "preserving equalizers" and "preserving regular monomorphisms"?

Tags: category-theory

I know that an arrow $e:a\to b$ in some category $\mathcal A$ is by definition a regular monomorphism if an object $c$ exists together with arrows $u,v:b\to c$ such that $e$ serves as equalizer of $u$ and $v$.

If also $\mathcal B$ is a category and $F:\mathcal A\to\mathcal B$ is a functor that **preserves equalizers** then - if I understood well - we are allowed to conclude that $Fe$ serves as equalizer of $Fu$ and $Fv$.

But what if $F$ is (only) said to **preserve regular monomorphisms**?

Is that exactly the same information about $F$ or is it less information because we are not allowed to conclude that regular monomorphism $Fe$ serves as equalizer of $Fu$ and $Fv$?

The best scenario is of course that it can be **proved** that in this situation $Fe$ is an equalizer of $Fu$ and $Fv$, but it seems to me that extra conditions are needed for that (or am I wrong here?).

Comment: According to *Abstract and Concrete Categories - The Joy of Cats* there is a difference between the two. $Fe$ may indeed be the equalizer of a different pair of morphisms. I don't know of an example right now on the top of my head, but a way of finding one would be picking $\mathcal{B}$ to be a category where every monomorphism is regular, and $F$ to be a monomorphism-preserving functor that doesn't preserve equalizers

Comment: Actually an example would be the following : pick a category $\mathcal{B}$ such that every monomorphism is regular. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the category with objects $1,2,3$, the identity maps, one map $1\to 2$, 2 distinct maps $2\to 3$ that compose to the same map $1\to 3$ with the map $1\to 2$. Clearly, $1\to 2$ is an equalizer of the maps $2\to 3$, and it is a monomorphism. Pick a diagram of the same shape in $\mathcal{B}$ that's not an equalizer diagram, but where the map is mono. You then get a regular mono-preserving functor, that doesn't preserve equalizers (cont)

Comment: (Cont) I think there can be a less ad hoc example though

Comment: @Max Thank you. Can you tell me on what page of JoC you found that there is indeed a difference? Also feel free (not forced) to make your comment an answer that can be upvoted and accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in the comments, in *Abstract and Concrete Categories- The Joy of Cats* one can read the following statement, page 116 (in the 2004 edition) "we will see that it is possible for a functor to preserve regular monomorphisms without preserving equalizers (13.6)".

A way to find such a counterexample is to pick a category $\mathcal{B}$ that has many regular monos, for instance one where all monos are regular ($\mathbf{Ab}, Set$, any topos,...) and a functor that preserves monos but not equalizers.

The (ad hoc) example I gave is the following: pick any such category $\mathcal{B}$ (for instance $Set$) , and three arrows $A\to B$, $B\to C, B\to C$ such that the arrow $A\to B$ equalizes the two other arrows, but is not an equalizer of them (and is a monomorphism).

Then pick $\mathcal{A}$ to be the diagram of an equalizer (that is a category with objects $1,2,3$ and arrows that compose in the obvious way- see my comment for more detail), and choose the obvious functor $F: \mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{B}$ sending $1\to A, 2\to B, 3\to C$.

Clearly this functor is a counterexample to "a functor preserving regular monos preserves equalizers"